# Python Beautiful Soup scrape only if text match?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just started learn beautiful soup, been watching videos and getting a hold of it somewhat. But examples provided, they seem already have a well structure in the HTML and not searching specific word anywhere.
What I try to do, is to print only the information of specific country mentioned, if it doesn't mention - it shouldn't print.
And later on will build so it append to text file.
I simply would like to grab everyone who is from new zealand, but to experiment I've been using United States because it's posted more frequently.

At the moment my code looks like this, it simply grabs all of them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://pogotrainer.club/?sort=worldwide').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

trainer = soup.find('article')
for box in trainer.find_all('div', class_='media-body'):
    print(box.text)
```

In one tutorial I saw they used findNext, since anyway the important is the friend code listed. So I tried doing so

```
usa = box.find(text="United States").findNext(class_="TCLink")
```

however printing it with print(usa), gives me error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'

Before as well, I've tried things like

```
usa = soup.find(text="United")
```

But it prints

> None

Even if looking at the page, it does have it.
Does anyone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'` let's break this down:

- The `NoneType object` is `box`
- You access the `attribute` with `.findNext` (which is actually a method) but because the object is `None`, the statement makes no sense.

You're assuming that `box` is not `None`, so you have to make sure what you're working with. You might want to try this:

```
for box in trainer.find_all('div', class_='media-body'):
    print(box)
```

Always try to know what you're working with by, for example, printing it explicitly.

That's one of Python's weaknesses (or strengths, depends on what you work on), it leaves this part of the debugging to the user.